# Why we use differential return with the average-reward settings for continuing tasks in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

What is the intuition behind using differential return with the average-reward settings for continuing tasks in reinforcement learning? Why can't we use the return defined as before.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? An example or the case/paper you are referring to?